# How can i get src as an attribute

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to getAttribute("src") of the image. When I run my script, it shows "null". BTW, action works!

My script:

```
WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.id("creativeLink"));
verifyDisplay(image.getAttribute("src"), By.id("creativeLink"));
action.moveToElement(image).perform();
```

Page HTML:

```
<div id="creativeContent">
<table>
<tbody><tr>
<td>

<a id="creativeLink" href="http://www.website.com" target="_new"> <img href="http://www.website.com" rel="faceboxMO" alt="" src="https://console.data.com/images/login/logo.png" height="50" border="0" width="50"></a>
</td>
<td valign="top"><div class="hint">(Note: Mouse over creative to see in correct dimensions)</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td></tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using wrong selector there. Since you are using some custom function I was not able to test it. However, I came up with something like following and seems working. A correct selector should look like something as following:

```
// The selector finds the img element
By by = By.cssSelector("#creativeLink>img");

//Getting attribute on on img tag
String src = driver.findElement(by).getAttribute("src");

System.out.println(src);
```

**Print**

```
https://console.data.com/images/login/logo.png
```

Probably do something like this and it will work:

```
WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#creativeLink>img"));
verifyDisplay(image.getAttribute("src"), By.cssSelector("#creativeLink>img"));
action.moveToElement(image).perform();
```

Comment: Nice, Saifur! You nailed it, again :)